# Gradle dependency resolution error, <exclude org: module="l:ame="*" type="*

Tags: gradle

When running the "war" task for a web application project using Gradle 1.10, the following error started showing up when I included a dependency on cxf-bundle 2.6.13:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
Could not resolve      <exclude org: module="l:ame="*" type="*.
Required by:
  :gradle_dep_issue_example:unspecified > org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:2.6.13
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
```

Stopping and starting the gradle daemon has no effect, nor does clearing out the .gradle folder. However, running the war task and passing the --refresh-dependencies option does resolve the issue. Unfortunately, the --refresh-dependencies option must be used every time.

Here is a small build.gradle file which will reproduce the issue when the "downloadRuntimeDeps" task is run.

```
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:2.6.13'
}

task downloadRuntimeDeps(type: Copy){
  from configurations.runtime
  into new File(getBuildDir(), "/runtime-deps/")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up only impacting gradle version 1.10. I tested with versions 1.8 and 1.11, and neither had this problem.

There are no bug fixes included in the [release notes for gradle 1.11](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.11/release-notes) that reference an issue like this, so I assume this was fixed while resolving a seemingly unrelated issue.

The solution was to upgrade all my projects to use gradle 1.11